# Why do HillTopAds VAST tags not work correctly with Google IMA SDK?

Tags: video.js, vast, imasdk

I'm encountering an issue with HillTopAds VAST tags not functioning as expected when integrated with the Google IMA SDK. Despite ensuring that the VAST tags are correctly formatted and conform to VAST specifications, I'm consistently getting an "AdError 1009" with the message "The response does not contain any valid ads."

When I check VAST tag with AdPlayerPro - https://adplayer.pro/developer/vast_inspector, vast Inspector I received

[First Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F8m9.png)

But when I check Vast Tag in https://googleads.github.io/googleads-ima-html5/vsi/

[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D9EC.png)

Do you have any ideas why?